errror when I run locally this colab python code
I have this code from this colab https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/eng-edu/blob/main/ml/cc/exercises/representation_with_a_feature_cross.ipynb
#@title Load the imports

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# The following lines adjust the granularity of reporting.
pd.options.display.max_rows = 10
pd.options.display.float_format = "{:.1f}".format

tf.keras.backend.set_floatx('float32')

print("Imported the modules.")

# Load the dataset
train_df = pd.read_csv("https://download.mlcc.google.com/mledu-datasets/california_housing_train.csv")
test_df = pd.read_csv("https://download.mlcc.google.com/mledu-datasets/california_housing_test.csv")

# Scale the labels
scale_factor = 1000.0
# Scale the training set's label.
train_df["median_house_value"] /= scale_factor

# Scale the test set's label
test_df["median_house_value"] /= scale_factor

# Shuffle the examples
train_df = train_df.reindex(np.random.permutation(train_df.index))

# Keras Input tensors of float values.
inputs = {
    'latitude':
        tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.float32,
                              name='latitude'),
    'longitude':
        tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.float32,
                              name='longitude')
}

#@title Define functions to create and train a model, and a plotting function
def create_model(my_inputs, my_outputs, my_learning_rate):

  model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=my_inputs, outputs=my_outputs)

  # Construct the layers into a model that TensorFlow can execute.
  model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.experimental.RMSprop(
      learning_rate=my_learning_rate),
      loss="mean_squared_error",
      metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()])

  return model


def train_model(model, dataset, epochs, batch_size, label_name):
  """Feed a dataset into the model in order to train it."""

  features = {name:np.array(value) for name, value in dataset.items()}
  label = np.array(features.pop(label_name))
  history = model.fit(x=features, y=label, batch_size=batch_size,
                      epochs=epochs, shuffle=True)

  # The list of epochs is stored separately from the rest of history.
  epochs = history.epoch

  # Isolate the mean absolute error for each epoch.
  hist = pd.DataFrame(history.history)
  rmse = hist["root_mean_squared_error"]

  return epochs, rmse


def plot_the_loss_curve(epochs, rmse):
  """Plot a curve of loss vs. epoch."""

  plt.figure()
  plt.xlabel("Epoch")
  plt.ylabel("Root Mean Squared Error")

  plt.plot(epochs, rmse, label="Loss")
  plt.legend()
  plt.ylim([rmse.min()*0.94, rmse.max()* 1.05])
  plt.show()

print("Defined the create_model, train_model, and plot_the_loss_curve functions.")

# The following variables are the hyperparameters.
learning_rate = 0.05
epochs = 30
batch_size = 100
label_name = 'median_house_value'

# The two Input layers are concatenated so they can be passed as a single
# tensor to a Dense layer.
preprocessing_layer = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()(inputs.values())

dense_output = layers.Dense(units=1, name='dense_layer')(preprocessing_layer)

outputs = {
  'dense_output': dense_output
}

# Create and compile the model's topography.
my_model = create_model(inputs, outputs, learning_rate)

# To view a PNG of this model's layers, uncomment the call to
# `tf.keras.utils.plot_model` below. After running this code cell, click
# the file folder on the left, then the `my_model.png` file.
# tf.keras.utils.plot_model(my_model, "my_model.png", show_shapes=True)

# Train the model on the training set.
epochs, rmse = train_model(my_model, train_df, epochs, batch_size, label_name)

# Print out the model summary.
my_model.summary(expand_nested=True)

plot_the_loss_curve(epochs, rmse)

print("\n: Evaluate the new model against the test set:")
test_features = {name:np.array(value) for name, value in test_df.items()}
test_label = np.array(test_features.pop(label_name))
my_model.evaluate(x=test_features, y=test_label, batch_size=batch_size)

It works on the cloud on colab
but locally I get error:
cd /home/dennisl/python ; /usr/bin/env /home/dennisl/python/.venv/bin/python /home/dennisl/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.debugpy-2024.4.0-linux-x64/bundled/libs/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher 44867 -- /home/dennisl/python/test7.py 
2024-04-16 14:21:38.207517: I external/local_tsl/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:32] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2024-04-16 14:21:38.211104: I external/local_tsl/tsl/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:32] Could not find cuda drivers on your machine, GPU will not be used.
2024-04-16 14:21:38.259509: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:210] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2024-04-16 14:21:39.195551: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
Imported the modules.
Defined the create_model, train_model, and plot_the_loss_curve functions.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dennisl/python/test7.py", line 97, in <module>
    preprocessing_layer = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()(inputs.values())
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/dennisl/python/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 122, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/home/dennisl/python/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/layers/layer.py", line 733, in __call__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Only input tensors may be passed as positional arguments. The following argument value should be passed as a keyword argument: dict_values([<KerasTensor shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32, sparse=None, name=latitude>, <KerasTensor shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32, sparse=None, name=longitude>]) (of type <class 'dict_values'>)

I have installed the libraries like this:
pip install numpy
pip install pandas
pip install tensorflow
pip install matplotlib

and I tried in 2 virtual enviroments with python 3.11.9 & 3.10.12

The problem is the difference between TF 2.15 (which is default right now on colab), and TF 2.16 (which you get as the newest version with pip install tensorflow).
In 2.16 this line is new for layers and looks out for KerasTensor objects or throws the error. The line in your code
inputs.values()

returns a dict_values object, not a list. Which triggers the error above. You can fix that with using an explicit list of the input values:
preprocessing_layer = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()(list(inputs.values()))


Additionally, I found another error in 2.16 after fixing that. The next error was thrown in the model.fit call and complained that the model has no loss function assigned. Which was really weird, because you call model.compile correctly.
This error is related to this issue, and I "fixed" it with using the dense layer directly and not the created dictionary

dense_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, name='dense_layer')(preprocessing_layer)

outputs = {
  'dense_output': dense_output
}

# Create and compile the model's topography.
my_model = create_model(inputs, dense_output, learning_rate)

This error seems unintentional or at least a bit weird, because it silently removes the loss function and not throws an error itself. If you don't need TF 2.16 specifically, I'd advise you to just use TF 2.15 locally for the moment.
